# Cannot re-add column to pandas multi-index dataframe after deletion

Tags: python, pandas

It seems odd that after deleting a column, I cannot add it back with the same name. So I create a simple dataframe with multi labeled columns and add a new column with level0 name only, and then I delete it.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> df.columns=[['a','b','c'],['e','f','g']]
>>> print(df)
   a  b  c
   e  f  g
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
>>> df['d'] = df.c+2
>>> print(df)
   a  b  c  d
   e  f  g   
0  1  2  3  5
1  4  5  6  8
>>> del df['d']
>>> print(df)
   a  b  c
   e  f  g
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Now I try to add it again, and it seems like it has no effect and no error or warning is shown.

```
>>> df['d'] = df.c+2
>>> print(df)
   a  b  c
   e  f  g
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Is this expected behaviour? Should I report a bugreport to pandas project? There is no such issue if I add 'd' columns with both levels specified, like this

```
df['d', 'x'] = df.c+2
```

Thanks,
PS: Python is 2.7.14 and pandas 0.20.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem your `MultiIndex` level are not removed after calling `del`:

```
del df['d']
print(df)
   a  b  c
   e  f  g
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Check columns:

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', '']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]])
```

Solution for remove is [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.remove_unused_levels()

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]])

df['d'] = df.c+2
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
   e  f  g   
0  1  2  3  5
1  4  5  6  8
```

---

Another solution is reaasign to MultiIndex, need `tuple` for select `MultiIndex` column:

```
df[('d', '')] = df.c+2
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
   e  f  g   
0  1  2  3  5
1  4  5  6  8
```

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks for your help!